# TypeORM migration binds id column to the object

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I created 2 tables in postgres - issues and projects. Each issue would come from a project so there's a project id foreign key that exist in the issues table.
After running "typeorm-model-generator" instead of getting a projectId field in issues with type number, I get a projectId of type project. Am I missing a setting here?

Database: postgres
TypeORM version: 0.1.12

```
@entity('Issue')
export class Issue {

@ManyToOne(type => Project, projectId => projectId.issues)
@JoinColumn({ name: 'projectId'})
projectId: Project; // this should be of type number and a new field called project should be created with type "project". 

...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using it this way in my entities:

```
@Entity()
export class Issue {

    @ManyToOne(type => Project, project => project.issues)
    project: Project

    @RelationId((issue: Issue) => issue.project)
    projectId: number;

    ...
}
```

It works properly, not sure if it's the best practice though.
Hope it helps.